# laravel 5 validation ajax rendering error response in javascript to show error in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

i have a form validation to validate my adding data into database. I am a beginner in using ajax/javascript. How could i display error in my view using ajax.

I have already json return from ajax by this code:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {    
             return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->messages(), 'status' => 422], 200);
}
```

in my view i have this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 {{ $errors->has('catname') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <input class="form-control" name="catname" placeholder="Category name" type="text" required />
        @if ($errors->has('catname'))
          <span class="help-block">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('catname') }}</strong>
              </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

how can i return the errors to make my input type display the error .

Here is my ajax.

```
function addCategoryAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({         
        url: "{{ route('admin.addcat') }}",        
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#frmAddcategory").serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
           if(data.status == 422) {
             for (var error in data.errors) {
                $('.errors').append(data.errors[error] + '<br>');
              }
           }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: chrome => developer toolts => network

Comment: @AnarBayramov thank you very much for your reply. hello sir i got this one in my network response :JSON
catname [1]
0 Category already exist. how can i do javascript to pass it on my view?

Comment: ajax call to laravel route -> laravel route -> controller -> view

Comment: i am asking for javascript to be passed in my view. because i don't know how to return it using javascript

Comment: where is your errors div? and you need to append each error as html element for example `$('.errors').append("<p>". data.errors[error] ."</p> ");`

Comment: @AmrAly how can i make my javascript error satisfy in my view {{ $errors->has('catname') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" and display the error text in if ($errors->has('catname'))
          <span class="help-block">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('catname') }}</strong>
              </span>
        endif

Comment: you can't do that because the code with `{{}}` is php code what you can do is to inject the dom as i have mentioned above you just need to have a div with class of `errors` then you can style the element as you wish

Comment: @AmrAly thanks can you give me some example so that i can follow?

Comment: @AmrAly something links or tutorial to do with it? thanks

Comment: check [this](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-ajax-request-validation-exampleexample.html)

Comment: hey @JcJohn did you get your solution? i am facing same

Answer (score -1):

```
function addCategoryAjax(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({         
    url: "{{ route('admin.addcat') }}",        
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#frmAddcategory").serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
       //if success
       console.log(data);
       alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data){
      //if error
      if(data.responseJSON == 422) {
         $('.errors').html('');
         for (var error in data.responseJSON) {
            $('.errors').append(data.responseJSON[error] + '<br>');
          }
       }
    }
}); 
}
```